# Oracle - ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error (DBMS_OUTPUT)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, dbms-output

I implemented a function that returns **clob** data-type, and I would like to print the result in **DBMS Output**. Unfortunately, I am getting **ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error** and I think it is due to the size of DBMS_OUTPUT.

This is the code.

```
DECLARE

    TYPE tp_col_array IS TABLE OF varchar2(32767); 
    FUNCTION my_fn (        
        p_in_proc_date IN varchar2)
        RETURN clob AS         
         vr_output_str clob;

        BEGIN            

        -- Detailed code hidden due to privacy. Sorry

        RETURN vr_output_str;

        EXCEPTION 
            WHEN LOGIN_DENIED
            THEN 
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid username/password: logon denied');
        RETURN 'TEST Terminated';

    END my_fn;

BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(my_fn('31-AUG-14'));    
END;
```

Here are something that can help you to understand this issue
1) Added the following to set the size of buffer **unlimited**, but did not work..

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(NULL);
```

or

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited;
```

Related link: http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=327
2) It is noted that the size of vr_output_str is **75387**, and that is why the return type is **CLOB**.

```
DBMS_LOB.getlength(vr_output_str); // =75387
```

3) I can solve the issue by doing the following, but I think this is not a **good solution** since it executed the function three times.

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR(my_fn ('31-AUG-14'), 1, 32767));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR(my_fn ('31-AUG-14'), 32768, 32767));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR(my_fn ('31-AUG-14'), 65536, 32767));
```

4) I am using **Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production**

Comment: Have you checked this https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:146412348066

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will not be able to print a clob using dbms_output.put_line directly if it is greater than 32767 bytes.

If this is the case you can create a procedure to iterate through the clob and print out one smaller chunk at a time. Such a procedure and test script is below:

```
declare 

  c clob;

  procedure print_clob( p_clob in clob ) is
      v_offset number default 1;
      v_chunk_size number := 10000;
  begin
      loop
          exit when v_offset > dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob);
          dbms_output.put_line( dbms_lob.substr( p_clob, v_chunk_size, v_offset ) );
          v_offset := v_offset +  v_chunk_size;
      end loop;
  end print_clob;


begin
  for i in 1..10000 loop
     c := c || 'test';
  end loop;
  --This will result in ora-06502
  --dbms_output.put_line(c);

  print_clob(c);

end;
```

Note that v_chunk_size must result in less than 32767 bytes being chunked at-a-time. If you encoding has 2 bytes per char you will need to use (32767/2).

Answer (score 1):

The following procedure will better:

- Oracle 10g has limitation on put_line (a maximum of 32767 characters), But Oracle before 10g has a maximum of 255 characters limitation.
- the 'put_line' adding end of line on every iteration loop during output clob. So we use put() better (and 'DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE' at end).

```
    PROCEDURE print_clob( p_clob in clob ) IS
        v_offset number default 1;
        v_chunk_size number := 255; 
      BEGIN
        LOOP
          EXIT when v_offset > dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob);
          dbms_output.put( dbms_lob.substr( p_clob, v_chunk_size, v_offset ) );
          v_offset := v_offset +  v_chunk_size;
        END LOOP;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;  
      END print_clob;
```