# dbms_output with dbms_lob.substr

Tags: database, oracle, substr, dbms-output

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26724110/2336497) I can loop a clob and print it using substr:

```
DECLARE
v_clob CLOB;
v_offset NUMBER DEFAULT 1;
v_chunk_size NUMBER := 10000;

BEGIN
    FOR I IN 1 .. 500 LOOP
        v_clob := v_clob || chr(10) || 'select '''||to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD')||''' date '||to_char(i)||' id FROM DUAL; ';
    END LOOP;

LOOP
    EXIT WHEN v_offset > dbms_lob.getlength(v_clob);
    dbms_output.put_line( dbms_lob.substr( v_clob, v_chunk_size, v_offset ) );
    v_offset := v_offset + v_chunk_size;
END LOOP;

END;
/
```

But why I'm getting this result? (not sequential):

```
select '2015-11-28' date 1 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 2 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 3 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 4 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 5 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 6 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 7 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 8 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 9 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 10 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 11 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 12 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 13 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 14 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 15 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 16 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 17 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 18 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 19 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 20 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 21 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 22 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 23 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 24 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 25 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 26 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 27 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 28 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 29 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 30 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 31 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 32 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 33 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 34 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 35 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 36 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 37 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 38 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 39 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 40 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 41 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 42 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 43 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 44 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 45 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 46 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 47 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 48 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 49 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 50 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 51 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 52 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 53 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 54 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 55 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 56 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 57 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 58 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 59 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 60 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 61 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 62 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 63 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 64 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 65 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 66 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 67 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 68 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 69 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 70 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 71 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 72 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 73 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 74 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 75 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 76 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 77 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 78 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 79 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 80 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 81 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 82 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 83 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 84 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 85 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 86 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 87 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 88 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 89 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 90 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 91 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 92 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 93 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 94 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 95 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 96 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 97 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 98 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 99 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 100 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 101 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 102 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 103 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 104 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 105 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 106 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 107 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 108 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 109 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 110 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 111 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 112 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 113 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 114 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 115 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 116 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 117 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 118 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 119 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 120 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 121 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 122 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 123 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 124 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 125 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 126 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 127 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 128 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 129 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 130 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 131 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 132 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 133 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 134 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 135 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 136 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 137 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 138 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 139 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 140 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 141 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 142 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 143 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 144 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 145 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 146 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 147 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 148 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 149 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 150 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 151 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 152 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 153 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 154 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 155 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 156 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 157 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 158 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 159 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 160 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 161 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 162 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 163 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 164 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 165 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 166 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 167 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 168 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 169 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 170 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 171 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 172 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 173 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 174 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 175 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 176 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 177 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 178 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 179 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 180 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 181 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 182 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 183 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 184 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 185 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 186 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 187 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 188 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 189 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 190 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 191 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 192 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 193 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 194 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 195 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 196 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 197 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 198 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 199 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 200 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 201 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 202 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 203 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 204 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 205 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 206 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 207 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 208 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 209 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 210 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 211 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 212 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 213 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 214 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 215 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 216 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 217 i
 FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 231 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 232 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 233 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 234 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 235 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 236 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 237 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 238 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 239 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 240 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 241 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 242 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 243 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 244 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 245 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 246 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 247 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 248 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 249 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 250 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 251 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 252 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 253 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 254 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 255 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 256 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 257 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 258 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 259 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 260 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 261 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 262 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 263 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 264 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 265 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 266 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 267 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 268 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 269 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 270 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 271 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 272 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 273 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 274 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 275 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 276 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 277 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 278 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 279 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 280 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 281 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 282 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 283 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 284 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 285 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 286 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 287 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 288 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 289 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 290 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 291 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 292 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 293 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 294 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 295 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 296 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 297 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 298 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 299 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 300 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 301 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 302 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 303 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 304 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 305 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 306 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 307 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 308 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 309 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 310 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 311 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 312 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 313 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 314 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 315 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 316 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 317 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 318 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 319 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 320 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 321 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 322 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 323 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 324 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 325 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 326 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 327 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 328 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 329 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 330 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 331 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 332 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 333 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 334 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 335 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 336 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 337 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 338 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 339 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 340 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 341 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 342 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 343 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 344 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 345 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 346 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 347 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 348 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 349 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 350 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 351 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 352 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 353 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 354 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 355 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 356 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 357 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 358 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 359 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 360 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 361 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 362 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 363 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 364 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 365 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 366 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 367 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 368 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 369 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 370 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 371 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 372 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 373 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 374 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 375 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 376 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 377 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 378 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 379 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 380 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 381 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 382 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 383 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 384 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 385 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 386 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 387 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 388 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 389 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 390 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 391 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 392 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 393 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 394 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 395 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 396 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 397 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 398 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 399 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 400 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 401 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 402 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 403 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 404 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 405 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 406 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 407 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 408 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 409 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 410 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 411 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 412 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 413 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 414 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 415 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 416 id FROM D89 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 190 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 191 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 192 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 193 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 194 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 195 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 196 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 197 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 198 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 199 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 200 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 201 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 202 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 203 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 204 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 205 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 206 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 207 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 208 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 209 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 210 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 211 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 212 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 213 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 214 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 215 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 216 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 217 i

select '2015-11-28' date 458 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 459 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 460 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 461 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 462 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 463 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 464 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 465 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 466 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 467 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 468 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 469 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 470 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 471 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 472 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 473 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 474 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 475 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 476 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 477 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 478 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 479 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 480 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 481 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 482 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 483 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 484 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 485 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 486 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 487 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 488 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 489 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 490 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 491 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 492 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 493 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 494 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 495 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 496 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 497 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 498 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 499 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 500 id FROM DUAL;
```

Is there a problem using dbms_lob.substr?

I'm using TOAD 10.1 and Oracle 11gR2.

Note: I intentionally ommited the ',' between date and id.

Thanks.

EDIT1: If you don't see in detail, the problems are:

1) a non sequential id and the "id" printed as "i":

```
select '2015-11-28' date 216 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 217 i
 FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 231 id FROM DUAL;
```

2) a non sequential id and "DUAL" printed as "D89":

```
select '2015-11-28' date 415 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 416 id FROM D89 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 190 id FROM DUAL;
```

3) a non sequential id, "id" printed as "i" and the extra breakline:

```
select '2015-11-28' date 216 id FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 217 i

select '2015-11-28' date 458 id FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: what's wrong with the result? you have this line `v_clob := v_clob || ...` and then you print content of your clob

Comment: @are the problem is in `select '2015-11-28' date 217 i
 FROM DUAL; 
select '2015-11-28' date 231 id FROM DUAL; ` is not sequential, and there are more like this

Answer (score 0):

I have concerns about `chunk_size=10000` if you change it to 255 it shows all lines in correct order

```
DECLARE
v_clob CLOB;
v_offset NUMBER DEFAULT 1;
v_chunk_size NUMBER := 255;

BEGIN
    FOR I IN 1 .. 500 LOOP
        v_clob := v_clob || chr(10) || 'select '''||to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD')||''' date '||to_char(i)||' id FROM DUAL; ';
    END LOOP;

LOOP
    EXIT WHEN v_offset > dbms_lob.getlength(v_clob);
    dbms_output.put_line( dbms_lob.substr( v_clob, v_chunk_size, v_offset ) );
    v_offset := v_offset + v_chunk_size;
END LOOP;

END;
```