# Create big xml on pl/sql

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I tried to create my xml-text:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT(
    "firms",
    XMLAGG(
        XMLELEMENT(
            "firm",c
            XMLELEMENT("FirmID", wo.id),
            XMLELEMENT("Name", substr(wo.namerus, 1, 120)),
            XMLELEMENT("ShortName", wo.code)           
        )
    )
)
INTO my_var
FROM organs wo
WHERE type_id = 5;

dbms_output.put_line(my_var.GetClobVal());
```

But then I got an error :

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

I know that my data is correct because if I doubled the first column three or more times I got this error again. How can i create a big xml?

Comment: What is MY_VAR's datatype? Did you try CLOB?

Comment: my_var XMLType;  Clob - Do you mean to create a long string into a clob variable?

Comment: CLOB *should* be large enough. Maybe it is DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE that is throwing an error, not SELECT itself. If that's so - so what? Don't *output* it, but do whatever you meant to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that the error arises not when you create the XML, but when you try to print it :

```
dbms_output.put_line(my_var.GetClobVal());
```

There are limitations to `dbms_output.put_line` that cause issues when processing large data : namely, clobs larger than 32k do fail to be printed this way, with error ORA-06502.

If you don’t actually need to *print* the clob, just comment out that line and you should be fine.

Else, have a look at [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723362/oracle-ora-06502-pl-sql-numeric-or-value-error-dbms-output), that provides a solution based on a procedure that iterates through the clob and prints out one smaller chunk at a time.

Comment: No... a number of error string shows to my select, not to output.

Comment: @Darya ok then can you pls post your whole script, including variable declaration, and the full error message, including line number ?

Comment: Also did you actually try to comment the line that prints the variable ?